# How to execute a stored procedure in Codeigniter with the Oracle Driver?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

How to execute a stored procedure in Codeigniter with the Oracle Driver ?
I have Oracle 10g and Codeigniter 2.1.2 .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it using CodeIgniter as it is specific to Oracle DB. There are two methods to workaround this.

1. You can always fallback and use pure PHP for tasks of this kind.
2. You can try running the command with `$this->db->call_function();` [description is available on the CI user guide here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/call_function.html)

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the answer that suggests using `$this->db->call_function('an_oracle_function()');` this does not work with Oracle 11g. Tried and tested. I think the better option is as mentioned by Vlakarados, is to use pure PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your model, this worked for me :

```
if (!$this->db) {
  $m = oci_error();
  trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, 'BEGIN PROCEDURE_NAME(:PARAMETER_1,:PARAMETER_2,:OUT_MESSAGE); end;');

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':PARAMAETER_1',  $PARAMAETER_1,200);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':PARAMETER_2',  $PARAMETER_2,200);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':OUT_MESSAGE',  $OUT_MESSAGE ,100, SQLT_CHR);

if(oci_execute($stid)){
  $results = $OUT_MESSAGE;
}
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($this->db->conn_id);

return  $results;
```